# How to trigger an event in jquery if an element is changed programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have several checkboxes with the same classes. When I checked the box also checked other checkboxes with the same classes. Also i have event handler `change` for checkboxes. After checked checkbox checked and others, all OK. But event handler called once. I need that called this event for each checkbox if this checkbox changed. How to do it?

My event handler:
`$('input[type="checkbox"]').on 'change', checkboxClick`

This checked or unchecked checkbox `$(className).not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)` - this also changed checkboxes with the same ClassName, but for others except `this` event handler not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.call()` to call named function `checkboxClick` within event handler, instead of dispatching `change` event

```
$(className).not(this).prop("checked", this.checked).each(function() {
  checkboxClick.call(this)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use .each function to apply all instances of that class.

```
$(className).each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
});
```